# May i use setContentView or Fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've an app with a lot of screens , instead of using activities i'm confused between using fragments or setContentview , if fragments are more efficient please tell me how can i do it with fragments.

Comment: Please use fragments that will help your app doesn't need to create many activities and improve performance.

Comment: @LiemVo can you tell me how to do that , i've googled this for three days with no answers , and can a fragment be used to occupe the entire screen and not a part of the activity's Layout ?

Comment: How to use Fragment? You can study from Android code lab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-create-and-add-fragment/#0

Answer (score 2):

> The simple answer is **NO, you may not use** `setContentView()` method
>   in `Fragment`

In `Fragment` you do not have a `setContentView()` method (it's only available in `Activity` class), instead you can inflate a layout as you would do with a custom `View`. Simply, you would want to override the `onCreateView()` method in your `Fragment` class (your class should extend `Fragment` to have this method available for overriding) and inflate the XML (for example say you have `you_fragment_layout.xml in your`main/res/layout`folder`) and your code would look like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_fragment_layout, container, false)
}
```

Comment: thanks , but i know that , my questions was about using `setContentview` **or** `Fragment` to go from a screen to another , and if you can tell me how to do this with `Fragment` i'll be grateful

Comment: @GayaTouak these are unrelated topics, I suggest you might want to follo a beginner level Android tutorial, you'll get the grasp of the basics. These are not things that can be explained simply here.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, You are quite confused about what needs to be used to implement an app with many screens i:e; whether fragments or creating multiple activities.

Although this is subjective ( you can use either fragments/ activities). I would recommend going with fragments and you know what? there is google's [navigation controller library](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) which is quite good in many cases. Comment below if you require any information.